# Setting cookie in php. Different ways to set cookie

Tags: php, cookies, header, setcookie

In how many ways you can set a cookie in php. How to set using header(). I have tried to set cookie in chrome using setcookie but it is not working. Want to know how to set using header().

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: What are you asking? What have you tried ? Codes please.

Comment: Just a heads up, questions need to show research effort, or you'll get mad downvotes and lose asking privileges.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I have tried to set cookie in chrome using setcookie but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `header('Set-Cookie: ...');` any other cookie that was set using `setcookie` will not be sent.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
setcookie('cookie_name', 'value', 'time');
echo $_COOKIE['cookie_name'];
```

This is simplest way to set the cookie in php you don't need any configruation for setcookie function. The third argument is optional, you can set time if you want.
Header is also a function which is usally use for redirect the page or for set the MIME type.
for example

```
header('location: index.php');
```